# chart.js doughnut chart, data only from two values? current value and max value

Tags: chart.js

I need to make a chart from two values. Current value and max. For example, if I have value 1, and max value is 2 = 1/2 = chart should say 50%/50%.

But when I do `data = [1, 2]` it shows me 33% and 66.7%. I know why this happens, but don't know how to solve it. It looks like very easy question, but I checked all sources and not found anything similar.

Like.. I want to make a progressbar 0-100% in a doughnut.
If user has solved 2 quizes of 4, chart should show 50% / 50%, as he solved half of quizes. I hope I explained

SOLVED.. it was so simple. `data = [currentValue, maxValue - currentValue];`